# Run JS code saved in a variable as string

Tags: javascript

I have a code saved in string. For eg:
`const code = "res.send("Hi")";`
How can I execute the above code in JS? I wanna execute the code of the `code` variable.
I can't just write `code;`. The code doesn't execute. Please Help.

Comment: [`eval(code)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) - but be careful, that is risky.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this? What is the context?

Comment: I need it to send message to multiple sockets

Comment: Why does that require you to have it in a string? Why not just call `res.send("Hi")`? Or put it in a function and call that function?

Comment: I'm looping `.to()` multiple times `socket.to("fi_GtczEsa1_tjBjAAAD").to("e07k37w3p880SJXDAAAH").emit("notifications", {notifications: [...newUser.notifications],})` to send the notifications to all the connected devices of the user.

Comment: [Then use a loop to chain the `.to()`](https://jsfiddle.net/r8a4smvh/) so you don't have to use a string. Having it in a string is not the way to go here.

Comment: @Ivar Thats a good way to do it. I'll use it instead of combining in string.

Answer (score 2):

use `eval`

```js
const code = "console.log('Hi')";

eval(code)
```